# Resetting row names after a reorder of data

Tags: r

I am a complete newbie to R. 
I am reorganizing data regarding 40-some students (i.d. by student #) on 5 different questions over 10 weeks.

So far I have managed to make my data(head) look like this:

```
 Student Question Type timePeriod week Rating
1  789331        Q  SNR        Rt1    1      4
2  789331       Q2  SNR        Rt1    1      3
3  789331       Q8  SNR        Rt1    1      4
4  789331      Q10  SNR        Rt1    1      4
5  789331      Q12  SNR        Rt1    1      3
6  805933        Q  SNR        Rt1    1      5
```

However, currently the data is organized by week, and I am trying to get all the student data to be together so I can cut the data based on student # in order to make graphs.

Using:

```
Sorted.student <- pulse1[order(pulse1$Student, decreasing = FALSE), ]
```

I was able to order the data by student #, but the rows are all still screwed up:

```
    Student Question Type timePeriod week Rating
1    789331        Q  SNR        Rt1    1      4
2    789331       Q2  SNR        Rt1    1      3
3    789331       Q8  SNR        Rt1    1      4
4    789331      Q10  SNR        Rt1    1      4
5    789331      Q12  SNR        Rt1    1      3
206  789331        Q  SNR        Rt2    2      4
```

How can I change the row names to make them be in order when sorted by student number?

Please let me know if this question doesn't make sense. I'm really new to R and potentially am not using the right lingo.

Comment: Do they need to be row names? What are you hoping for them to look like? What would "in order" mean in this context?

Comment: @BLT
I want the row numbers to start from 1 and increase by 1 in a list. Originally it did this, but when I sorted by student #, it also sorted the row numbers, so now instead of being in order (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6) it goes 1,2,3,4,5,206. 
Is there a way to keep the data sorted so all data with the same student number are together, while also changing the row numbers so they start at 1 and ascend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rownames(Sorted.student)<-1:nrow(Sorted.student)
```

Comment: Also, `rownames(temp) <- NULL` which "deletes" the rownames and allows R to fill them in with the default.